# How To Properly Setup HTTP or HTTPS PROXY in Deno

Tags: javascript, proxy, fetch, deno

so i tried to fetch some resource ( filtered in my country ) with **[Deno](https://deno.land/)** 
i opened `Environment Variables` window in *windows* and under the *User Variables* Section add 
*Variable Name: `HTTP_PROXY`* 
*Variable Value: `195.45.78.1 : 25`* `[fake!]`
but at the end i cant fetch resource it seems deno do not use that proxy, i tried at least 10 proxies i must mention that all of them was free proxies

*maybe setup proxy wrong ... ?*

Comment: Do any of the resources you are trying to proxy use `https`? You might need to set `HTTPS_PROXY` instead of or in addition to `HTTP_PROXY`.

Comment: so i did what you said... i get different error this time  deno say : `error trying to connect: invalid dnsname`

Comment: that's at least progress! :D my guess at this point is that you have something misconfigured or something but at least it looks like Deno is indeed recognizing your environment variables

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set `HTTPS_PROXY` in addition to (or instead of) `HTTP_PROXY` as most (perhaps all) of the resources you'll be downloading and fetching with Deno will use `https`.

Reference: [Proxies | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.11.3/linking_to_external_code/proxies#proxies)